# Multiple NamedStyle in a single excel sheet - Python openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to give styling to multiple cells in a excel worksheet. The sheet has multiple tables in it. The table headers have bold font and normal border whereas the table data has only order.

I have defined 2 NamedStyle and attached to workbook. But when when the style to cells i am getting below error .

```
book.add_named_style(tableHeaderStyle)
File "C:\Users\bsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 303, in add_named_style
    self._named_styles.append(style)
File "C:\Users\bsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\named_styles.py", line 194, in append
    raise ValueError("""Style {0} exists already""".format(style.name))
ValueError: Style TableHeaderStyle exists already
```

Code:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side, Color, PatternFill, Font, Alignment, NamedStyle
my_border = Border(left=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'),
                right=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'),
                top=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'),
                bottom=Side(border_style='thin', color='000000'))

normalBorderStyle = NamedStyle(name="NormalBorderStyle",
                           alignment=Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True), border=my_border)

tableHeaderStyle = NamedStyle(name="TableHeaderStyle", alignment=Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center'), border=my_border, \
                               font=Font(bold=True), \
                                fill=PatternFill(patternType='solid', fill_type='solid', fgColor=Color('C4D79B')))

#This function is called for a table in worksheet "ws" with the cell range as the start and end column of table "B3:G7".
def set_border(ws, cell_range):
    flag = 0
    for row in ws.iter_rows(cell_range):
        for cell in row:
            cell.style = "NormalBorderStyle"
            if flag ==0 :
                cell.border = "TableHeaderStyle"
        flag = 1

book = load_workbook(xlsfile)
book.add_named_style(tableHeaderStyle)
book.add_named_style(normalBorderStyle)
ws_active = book.get_sheet_by_name("Summary")
set_border(ws_active, "B3:G7")
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: @CharlieClark Please find below the trace:  

 book.add_named_style(tableHeaderStyle)
 File "C:\Users\bsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 303, in add_named_style
  self._named_styles.append(style)
 File "C:\Users\bsingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\named_styles.py", line 194, in append
  raise ValueError("""Style {0} exists already""".format(style.name))
 ValueError: Style TableHeaderStyle exists already

Comment: Please put the traceback in your question, makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yes updated the question, was not able to update the comment after 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

It looks very much like the style already exists in the book you're loading because the exception is not related to your function. You might want to add a check using `book.named_styles`.

Comment: Yes there is a named style associated with the book. But i tried to remove the worksheet and add it again, but still getting the error. Do i have to remove the named style from the entire workbook or i can remove it from the worksheet if any such option ?

Comment: Named styles are per workbook and the exception is correct because you're trying to create a duplicate style. The styles are editable but I'd always suggest using a different name rather than editing default styles.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to register the style only once, so you can add it using a condition given below.

```
if 'NormalBorderStyle' not in book.style_names:
    book.add_named_style(normalBorderStyle)

# Directly Use as:
ws['D5'].style = 'NormalBorderStyle'
```

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to use the cell_range as you have defined it, you would have to use slicing notation, i.e., `ws[cell_range]`. The documentation states it this way:

> Accessing many cells Ranges of cells can be accessed using slicing:
>
> > `cell_range = ws['A1':'C2']`

Also, if you wanted to use rows instead,  as per the documentation, the input parameters for `iter_rows()` must be integers and not the cell ranges as you have defined them.

> You can also use the Worksheet.iter_rows() method:
>
> `for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=2):`

The other thing I noticed in your code is that you were trying to modify the `border` attribute of the cell with a `NamedStyle` instead. As @Arpan pointed out, you need to register your named styles with the workbook once it has been loaded. Then you can access them using the value of their `name` attribute.

Lastly, as of this writing, the `get_sheet_by_name` method is `deprecated`, you need to use `wb[sheet_name]` instead.

With all those highlighted changes, the following (tested on `Python 3.6` and `openpyl 3.0.6`) should work.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import (
    Border,
    Side,
    Color,
    PatternFill,
    Font,
    Alignment,
    NamedStyle,
)

my_border = Border(
    left=Side(border_style="thin", color="000000"),
    right=Side(border_style="thin", color="000000"),
    top=Side(border_style="thin", color="000000"),
    bottom=Side(border_style="thin", color="000000"),
)

normalBorderStyle = NamedStyle(
    name="NormalBorderStyle",
    alignment=Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center", wrap_text=True),
    border=my_border,
)

tableHeaderStyle = NamedStyle(
    name="TableHeaderStyle",
    alignment=Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center"),
    border=my_border,
    font=Font(bold=True),
    fill=PatternFill(patternType="solid", fill_type="solid", fgColor=Color("C4D79B")),
)

# This function is called for a table in worksheet "ws" with the cell range as the start and end column of table "B3:G7".
def set_border(ws, cell_range):
    flag = 0
    for row in ws[cell_range]:
        # apply the styles to the cells
        for cell in row:
            cell.style = normalBorderStyle.name
            if flag == 0:
                cell.style = tableHeaderStyle.name
        flag = 1


excelfile_path = "path_to_file"
book = load_workbook(excelfile_path)

# Register the named style cell formats to the workbook if they
# don't exist already
if tableHeaderStyle.name not in book.style_names:
    book.add_named_style(tableHeaderStyle)
if normalBorderStyle.name not in book.style_names:
    book.add_named_style(normalBorderStyle)

ws_active = book["Summary"]
set_border(ws_active, "B3:G7")
book.save(excelfile_path)
```